# Verify that Login link selected by default

Tags: javascript, automation, protractor

Login Link here

```
it('CDTR_Page_001 - Verify LoginPage fields - {Logo,Login,SignUp,Login Selected by default}', () => {

    loginpage.LoginPage().logo.getLocation().then((location) => {
        expect(location.height).toBe(51);
        expect(location.width).toBe(213);
    });
    expect(loginpage.LoginPage().logo.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(loginpage.LoginPage().login_link.isDisplayed()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(loginpage.LoginPage().login_link.isEnabled()).toBeTruthy();
    expect(loginpage.LoginPage().login_link.isSelected()).toBeTruthy();
});
```

[image]

Comment: It is unclear what are you seeking. Can you please clarify your question and add a desired output?

Comment: Can you include the error you are getting? From what I read, you are trying to assert that `loginpage.LoginPage().login_link.isSelected()` is true

Comment: @Mirakurun:- I am launching an app and after launching I have two options. Login and SignUp. When app is launched then Login frame should be displayed by default but not SignUp frame.

Answer (score 2):

I think in this case `isSelected()` is not gonna work. It's mostly for checkboxes, though I've used it with tab elements, but they don't always work with this method.
Can you share how the element looks (the Login tab) when it's selected/highlighted (blue)?
You might need to do something like `.getAttribute()` instead